# Relatively Prime Relationship Equation Proof

Tags: proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm

I have this math question that I am stuck on. This is the question:

> Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, with $d = \gcd(a, b)$.
>    Suppose that there exists integers $r$ and $s$ so that $ar + bs= d$. 
>    Show that $\gcd(r, s) = 1$ using the relatively prime equation.

This is the relatively prime relationship equation: Let $a,b$ be non-zero integers. $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime iff there exists integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=1$

I know that the relatively prime equation that I have to solve is $ar + bs = 1$. However, I'm not sure how to start this. Thanks.

Comment: What is this "relatively prime equation"? As stated, you can't use [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) because that's what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @A.P. Let $a,b$ be non-zero integers. $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime iff there exists integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=1$

Comment: That's a special case of what you are trying to prove.

Comment: So, how do I show it using that equation? I don't start off with the equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dividing $a$ and $b$ by $d$, we have two relatively prime numbers.  By the relatively prime numbers equation, it exist $r$ and $s$ such that

$r\frac{a}{d} + s\frac{b}{d} = 1.$

Those numbers are relatively prime.  If not, the left part could be factorise giving an integer factorisation of 1...

Multiplying everything by $d$ again to obtain what you need

Comment: How is that using the Relatively Prime Relationship Equation?

Comment: Since $\frac{a}{d}$ and $\frac{b}{d}$, there is $r$ and $s$ such that $r\frac{a}{d} = s\frac{b}{d}=1$.  $r$ and $s$ are relatively prime.

Comment: +1: The idea's there, but you should try to flesh-out your answers a bit more. Right now this is more a comment than an answer...

Comment: My goal was to give you a hint, I will flesh out my solution.

Answer (score 3):

We know that $a = d\bar{a}$ and $b = d\bar{b}$, so dividing
$$
ar + bs = d
$$
by $d$ we get
$$
\bar{a}r + \bar{b}s = 1
$$
which is what you call the "relatively prime equation", hence $r$ and $s$ must be coprime.

To conclude without assuming this, just suppose that there is an $f > 1$ that divides both $r$ and $s$. Then the above equation implies $f \mid 1$, which is absurd.